# Graphics2D does PostModern

Tags: java, swing, graphics, graphics2d

In the following code changing `fill` to `draw` produces unexpected results. The attached image demonstrates the undesired but much appreciated postmodern effect caused by `draw`ing the red and green rectangles.

The affine transform should not be part of the problem, but as Holmes said, once you rule out all other possibilities ... So, I will explain the transform. I solved a bunch of equations to figure out how to make the window show a cartesian coordinate system with `(-2, -2)` in the lower left and `(+2, +2)` in the upper right.

This is a self-contained example. Try changing any of the `draw`s to a `fill` or vice versa to achieve your own custom art that you can frame in the Oracle office.

I am using Java SE 7, JDK 1.7.0_21!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class G {

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(G.class.getCanonicalName());
    JComponent component = new JComponent() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        AffineTransform xform = new AffineTransform(getWidth() / 4, 0, 0, - getHeight() / 4, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        g2.setTransform(xform);
        paint2D(g2);
        g2.dispose();
      }

      protected void paint2D (Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double( 0,  0, 1, 1));
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(-1, -1, 1, 1));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(-1,  0, 1, 1));
        g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double( 0, -1, 1, 1));
      }
    };
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

[image: graphics2_postmodern.png]

Comment: And ..what is your question?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought `fill` and `draw` should produce the same rectangle...?

Comment: @randomstring , Fill and Draw are both different , Fill will color the whole rectangle, and Draw just Outline the rectangle with color

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer yes it is the stroke width getting magnified like crazy!

Comment: @randomstring , oke first tell me, what you exactly looking for?

Comment: oo I c, the fill and draw both have same results, that's makes you confused. let me check ...!!

Comment: *"I thought fill and draw should produce the same rectangle...?"*  Putting a '?' on the end of a statement does not make it a question.  Sheesh, it ain't rocket science..

Comment: @AndrewThompson the opening sentence in my original question says: "changing fill to draw produces UNEXPECTED results" the next sentence says: "the attached image demonstrates the UNDESIRED ... results".

Comment: to help the frustrated readers empathize, this happened after a long slog to correctly scale the drawing area to a mathematical coordinate system ranging from -1 to +1 with the origin at lower left. while figuring out the scaling i took somebody's help who used fill in their code rather than draw (without explaining why they edited my code to use fill rather than draw). i could not recreate their solution in my code until i flipped draw to fill, and then this question arose. i have to say today has been a wtf day for java swing and graphics.

Comment: for art purists, this piece came about organically. it was the actual test case i was using before knowing about the bug and before knowing it would show up this way. i started with 4 fills and started changing to a draw and then this happened without my knowing the cause until after i posted the question. it wasn't contrived for attention :) even the sequence of the fills changed to draws is original - with other sequences graphics2d would have interpreted it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is the 1 unit default stroke setting. i increased the coordinate space from `-20` to `+20` in each dimension and drew `10` unit wide and high rectangles which confirmed the problem as the image below shows.

[image: less modern]